# Series sum Diverge or Converge??

Tags: power-series, divergent-series

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n-1}{(n+2)(n+3)}
\end{equation}

The answer was Divergent, but I solved it as Convergent by using limit comparison test.
plz help me solving this question.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! If you show us your calculation, we can tell you where you did a mistake.

Comment: Limit comparison test is a good route. We can compare the given series to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n$ which is a divergent series.

Comment: @EuklidAlexandria After read answer, I found my mistake. I thought \sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n is convergent :O Thx for kind comment!

Comment: @Mason Yes. I thought limit comparison test is the only way to solve this problem. But there was another way!

Comment: @Chatanee No problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use partial fraction decomposition to rewrite
$$\frac{n-1}{(n+2)(n+3)}=\frac{4}{n+3}-\frac{3}{n+2}=\frac{1}{n+3}+3\left(\frac{1}{n+3}-\frac{1}{n+2 } \right)$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n-1}{(n+2)(n+3)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n+3}+3\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n+3}-\frac{1}{n+2 } \right)$$ The second summation telescopes and then
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n-1}{(n+2)(n+3)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n+3}-1$$

Answer (score 1):

$(n+2)(n+3) = n^{2} + 5n + 6 \leq n^{2} + 5n^{2} + 6n^{2} \leq 13n^{2}$

And $n-1 \geq \frac{n}{2}$ for all $n > 1$

Then $\frac{n-1}{(n+2)(n+3)} \geq \frac{\frac{n}{2}}{13n^{2}} = \frac{1}{26n}$

Thus $\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \frac{n-1}{(n+2)(n+3)} \geq \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{26n} = \frac{1}{26} \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} = \infty$

Then by comparison $\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \frac{n-1}{(n+2)(n+3)}$ is divergent $\implies \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{n-1}{(n+2)(n+3)}$ is divergent

Comment: You made a small computational error in the first line: $n^2+5n^2+6n^2=12n^2$, not $13n^2$. Also, you should qualify the first _Then_ assertion with the restriction that $n>1$. The rest looks fine, once you correct for the computational error.

Comment: thank you! I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

$$
\left. \frac{n-1}{(n+2)(n+3)} \, \right/ \frac 1 n \to 1 \text{ as } n\to\infty.
$$
Therefore
$$
\left. \frac{n-1}{(n+2)(n+3)} \, \right/ \frac 1 n > 0.9 \text{ for large enough values of } n.
$$
So
$$
\frac{n-1}{(n+2)(n+3)} > \frac{0.9} n \text{ for large enough values of }n.
$$
So by a simple comparison test, the series considered diverges to $+\infty.$